# docker issue with namespaces - Container ID 110090219 cannot be mapped to a host ID

Tags: linux, macos, docker

when I try to pull a docker image to a machine (which I am not a sudo on), I am getting an error 
`failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: Container ID 110088952 cannot be mapped to a host ID.`

I found a [trouble-shooting page](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_troubleshoot.html#container_troubleshoot) that says this error is the usernamespace feature is turned on and it requires that the container id must be between 0 and 65536.  I checked with `docker info` and it does appear to be on:

```
Security Options:
 userns
```

**My question is: how do i get around this issue?**  I have no idea how to make sure the "container ids are in the range 0 and 65536"...  They suggest turning on namespaces on the computer I build the image on, but the command they suggest does not work on my mac:

```
$ sudo docker daemon --userns-remap=default
docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'.
```

Comment: The recent docker installation for mac allows you to configure the daemon straight from the UI. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#custom-registries (look for "EDIT THE DAEMON CONFIGURATION FILE").

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that's the right way to go but I managed to do that by changing the `/etc/subgid` and `etc/subuid` helped me - if you specify `default` in `userns-remap` it would create a user called `dockremap` and automatically add records to `/etc/subgid` and `/etc/subgid`.

Read more about it [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/subuid.5.html) but it's important that the container ID would be in the valid uid range. if not - change the range.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not `docker daemon ...` but `dockerd ...`? Don't forget to kill `dockerd` first, before you launch your commands.